R arrow - add a column to a Parquet dataset based on vector with indexes from another column
In this post I asked how to add a vector as a new column to a Parquet dataset / Arrow table without loading the table in RAM.
Now, is it possible to create the new column based on a vector and with indexes coming from the Arrow table?
With data loaded in RAM, it is straightforward, the desired output would be:
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt = data.table(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
z = c(11,12,13,14)
dt |> mutate(z = z[x])
#       x      y     z
#   <num> <char> <num>
#1:     1      a    11
#2:     2      b    12
#3:     3      c    13
#4:     2      d    12
#5:     1      e    11
#6:     3      f    13

Is it possible without loading the data in memory, with an Arrow table?
library(data.table)
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

dt = data.table(x = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
z = c(11,12,13)
write_parquet(dt, "dt.parquet")
ds = open_dataset("dt.parquet")

ds |> as_arrow_table() |> cbind(z = z[x])
# error x not found

This could be achieved by only loading column x in memory and not the full table but still with large files that could lead to large memory consumption.

You could do something like this
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)


dt = data.table::data.table(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
z = c(11,12,13,14)
write_parquet(dt, "dt.parquet")
ds = open_dataset("dt.parquet")

ds = open_dataset("dt.parquet")

external = data.frame(x = 1:length(z), z = z) |>
  to_duckdb()


ds |>
  to_duckdb() |>
  left_join(external, by = 'x') |>
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>       x y         z
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 a        11
#> 2     2 b        12
#> 3     3 c        13
#> 4     4 d        14
#> 5     2 e        12
#> 6     4 f        14

Created on 2024-08-14 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks a lot! I'd like to save the joined table to a new Parquet file without collecting in RAM, do you think it's possible? Instead of collect() I tried to_arrow() |> write_parquet() but that also loads data in RAM. I think it might be possible with DuckDB based on this discussion but I was not able to do the same with my use case.
